# Changing the value of a DependencyProperty inside the PropertyChangedCallback for that DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, dependency-properties, onchange

I have a control with a `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="TraceComboBox"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SingleChannelList}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource  FindAncestor,
                         AncestorType={x:Type cc:LogicTriggerSimpleLevelControl}},
                         Path=SelectedTrace, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Here's the `PropertyChangedCallback` for the Property `SelectedTrace` in the OuterControl containing the `ComboBox`:

```
private static void OnSelectedTraceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OuterControl oc = d as OuterControl ;
    oc.UpdateSelectedTrace();
}

private void UpdateSelectedTrace()
{
    ViewModelType vm = DataContext as ViewModelType;
    if (vm != null)
    {
        if (vm.SingleChannelList != null)
        {
            SelectedTrace = vm.SingleChannelList[0];
        }
    }
}
```

By my logic, the following should happen:

I select the 3rd object in the `ComboBox` (`SingleChannelList[2]`), and the change handler occurs.  It then goes into the `UpdateSelectedTrace()` routine.  At this point, the value of `SelectedTrace` is of course `SingleChannelList[2]`.  Now, the `UpdateSelectedTrace()` routine forcibly sets the `SelectedTrace` property to the 1st object in the list (`SingleChannelList[0]`), which fires another change handler nested inside the first.  **"SelectedTrace" now equals SingleChannelList[0], and so the ComboBox should also show SingleChannelList[0] as its selection.**

ALL of this happens when I follow with the debugger until the bold-faced last sentence, which instead plays out like this:

`SelectedTrace` now equals `SingleChannelList[0]`, but the `ComboBox` displays `SingleChannelList[2]` as its selected item.  I tried `UpdatingTarget` on the `BindingExpression` and still, the `SelectedTrace` Property holds the value `SingleChannelList[0]` while the `ComboBox` continues to show `SingleChannelList[2]`.   These bindings are secure and tested and have always worked until I tried to do this.  Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work correctly?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a scenario for dependency property 'value coercion'. Value coercion 'pushes' the value of the property to a valid value based on a desired value. Read more about it here:

[Dependency Property Callbacks and Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx)

Comment: I found that given that the original change originates from the box that is changing, this still doesn't work.  Instead I just hard set the box after everything is done and it works fine.  Hacky but works.  The real question is WHY doesn't my original scenario work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a performance optimization by the WPF framework.  The origin of the property update doesn't get a propertychanged event (well, the binding equivalent) to re-update itself, since it is the origin of the change.  You can force an update using an IdentityConverter (ValueConverter that just returns the value passed in) in the Binding.